# How can I execute code after rendering in Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have some long running code that I'd like to execute after rendering in a Mojolicious app.

I'd like to avoid using [Minion](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Minion) queues as I'd be calling many very short processes, and I've looked into [Mojolicious::Plugin::ForkCall](http://search.cpan.org/~jberger/Mojo-IOLoop-ForkCall/) and [Mojolicious::Plugin::Subprocess](http://search.cpan.org/~dbook/Mojolicious-Plugin-Subprocess/) but they both timeout (as the short processes get called many times).

I remember coming across an example of this somewhere but cannot find it anymore.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `fork` in an [`after_dispatch`](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious#after_dispatch) hook?

```
$app->hook(after_dispatch => sub {
  my $c = shift;
  my $pid = fork();
  if (defined($pid) && $pid == 0) {
      doSlowStuff();
      exit;
  }

});
```

Comment: thanks - it looks like it works but is it possible to do for only one route in a lite  - as opposed to for every dispatch? I don't need it all the time - only on some responses.

Comment: Timer with fork() then? http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/IOLoop#timer

Comment: Yep - I found out thanks to your answer. https://gist.github.com/simonecesano/0ed2163c2ba4e635d458611963027762. Want to edit so I can accept the answer?